# How to solve this expression: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(x-3)^{2n-1}}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, power-series

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(x-3)^{2n-1}}$$

How to change the given expression to a rational function

Comment: Parentheses please.  Yours are unbalanced.  Is the whole $2n-1$ supposed to be in the exponent?  Are we summing over $n$, maybe from $1$ to $\infty$?  If the last two answers are yes, you have a geometric series.  Do you know how to sum them?

Comment: 1/(x-3)^2n-1 that's what I meant

Comment: yes we are summing from 1 to infinity

Comment: Do you recognize the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)?  Do you know how to sum them?

Comment: yes I do it's 1/1-x

Comment: No, you have a geometric series.  The ratio of successive terms is $(x-3)^{-2}$  The sum is not $\frac 1{1-x}$

Comment: I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the sum as
$$\frac{1}{x-3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(x-3)^2}\right)^n.$$
Now, for any real number $r$ with $-1<r<1$, it is well known that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n=\frac{1}{1-r}$$
so *only* if $x<2$ or $x>4$ we can conclude that the desired sum is equal to
$$\frac{1}{x-3}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{1}{x-3}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{x-3-\frac{1}{x-3}}=\frac{x-3}{(x-3)^2-1}=\frac{x-3}{x^2-6x+8}.$$
This means that if $2\leq x\leq 4$ then you cannot rewrite the sum as a fraction.

Comment: thank you so much I have couple more questions can you help me with them?

Comment: On MSE, just post them.

Comment: I'm bad at editing the question because I'm new here

Comment: Just post, the principle of MSE partly is that badly frased questions can be edited by others. The community will boost itself.

Comment: well it says that I got blocked and I can't ask a question and I have to wait for 2 days

Comment: I'm afraid that is because you can ask questions more frequent if you have more rep. Take a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Answer (score 0):

First, make the series zero-based (as the geometric series is zero-based).

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}\dfrac{1}{(x-3)^{2n-1}} = \sum_{n\ge 0} \dfrac{1}{(x-3)^{2n+1}}$$

Next, pull out $\frac{1}{x-3}$:

$$\dfrac{1}{x-3}\sum_{n\ge 0} \left(\dfrac{1}{(x-3)^2}\right)^n = \dfrac{1}{x-3}\cdot \dfrac{1}{1-\tfrac{1}{(x-3)^2}} = \dfrac{x-3}{(x-3)^2-1}, \left|\dfrac{1}{(x-3)^2}\right| < 1$$

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is a geometric series of common ratio $(x-3)^{-2}$ and initial term $(x-3)^{-1}$.

Hence for

$$(x-3)^{-2}<1,$$ the sum converges to

$$\frac{(x-3)^{-1}}{1-(x-3)^{-2}}.$$

Comment: thank you so much!!